# pip.config file, how to add credentials git private repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, google-cloud-platform, pip

I'm using GCP with apache Airflow, and need to install a Python dependency from a private repository in github.

The GCP docs is somewhat non clear on how i should pass my credentials, and so is the pip docs.

from the GCP docs:

- Access credentials for the repository
- Non-default pip installation options

Example:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://github.com/my_private_repo_example
```

How do i pass my credentials, or even better a Token with read-only rights.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ssh client is properly configured, something like this should be good enough:

```
pip install git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
```

From the [`pip install` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git).

The modification to the `pip.config` file is not necessary.